# Add wallpaper banner Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, banner

Working on banners on a Joomla website. I want to have wallpaper banners, as seen on this screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

Banners are present on the left and right side.
Is there a way to do this easily ? Or have I to completely override the com_banners component and the mod_banners module ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create two Banner Category in the Banner component. left and right. add items to those banner category. 
Then go to your `extension menu -> Module manager -> Add new module ->` choose existing banner module from the list.
set a left position available on your template , then apply on all pages.
publish it.

If you need rotating banners you can use [my module extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/photos-a-images/slideshow/wwm-banner-slideshow).

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Going to try. What do you mean by "add items to those banner category" ? Do I create a banner with the left category and another one with the right category ? Thanks

Comment: yes. If you're trying to make a full bg image then only one banner category required, but you may need to edit the template file and set position according to that.

Comment: Allright, so I created two categories, two banners and two banners modules. Now I'm trying to create two new positions in my template to set my banners where I want